# Why do people keep reusing superclass names in their subclasses?

Tags: python, naming, inheritance, django, python-3.x

In my project, I found one of the project's classes reusing the same name as an official one.

For example:

```
from django.db import models


class Model(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I had learnt from the senior and my experiences that I should use `AbstractTimestamp` because:

1. Less hassle since the name is clear and reflects what that class is doing
2. Auto-complete will be pop-up with single choice to choose
3. When we talk to people in the project we don't need to mention about header
4. Less bug in the header part

Given that:

1. Why do people keep reusing superclass names in their subclasses?
2. Are there any benefits from this?

Comment: What do you mean by "header"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally there are two schools of thought on this:

1. Multiple types with the same name are fine if the name makes sense for them all. Differentiate them via a package/namespace/module etc name.
2. Avoid multiple types with the same name as one then has to reply on the package/namespace/module etc name to differentiate them, which can be confusing.

As a general rule, neither of these is "correct" and neither is "wrong". It depends on circumstance. If I provide a library with different implementations of a model, I might choose to call them both `Model`, clarifying their difference via different module names, eg `myLib.mutable.modelProvider` and `myLib.immutable.modelProvider`.

However, what I'd regard as a serious code smell would be to have a base class, `Model` and to then add loads of extra features to it via a child class and to still call the latter, `Model` too. That's just laziness. You've added to `Model`, so give it a name that describes those additions.

And this seems to be what you are describing:

```
class Model(models.Model):
  class Meta:
    abstract = True

  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

is extending `Model` with timestamps. So call it something like `TimestampedModel`. This avoids confusion over the name and provides a description of the additions.

I've never come across someone reusing the superclass name in their subclasses in this way before. The only benefit I can see to this is it saves putting any effort into coming up with a new name. Sure, naming is hard; but "it's hard" is not an excuse for being lazy.

Comment: I typically use `BaseModel` for situations like this. Yes, you can make the argument that you can always clarify with a package/module, but that becomes problematic as soon as you do something like `from myproject.models import Model`. Someone who is reading through the code later on shouldn't have to rely on reading the import statements to resolve ambiguities.